# QInputDialog в классе Dialog работает не так как хотелось

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

При нажатии кнопки `pushbutton` и выборе элемента **`A`** или **`B`** всё нормально, но когда нажимаю кнопку и жму `Cancel` *несколько раз*, то `QInputDialog` появляется несколько раз?

Я хочу использовать один **`Диалог`** выбора, но с разными параметрами, а не создавать для каждого случая отдельный класс с диалогом это возможно?

**design.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

**dialog.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(Dialog)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 256, 192))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "1")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
import design
from dialog import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
 
 
 
 
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent
  
    def Aload(self):
        self.treeWidget.clear()
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, "A")
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.addA)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
 
    def addA(self):
            text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Добавить', 'Введите название')
            return text
            self.close()
    
    def Bload(self):
        self.treeWidget.clear()
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, "B")
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.addA)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
 
    def addB(self):
            text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Добавить', 'Введите название')
            return text
            self.close()
 
 
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.add_functions()
        self.dialog = Dialog(self)
 
    def add_functions(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.A)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.B)
 
    def A(self):
        self.dialog.Aload()
        self.dialog.exec()
 
    def B(self):
        self.dialog.Bload()
        self.dialog.exec()
 
 
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Достон, вы забыли опубликовать модули `design.py` и `dialog.py`

Comment: Я хочу использовать один Диалог выбора но с разными параметрами , а не создавать для каждого случая отдельный класс с диалогом это возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не в том месте выполняете привязку сигналов и слотов.

```
import sys
# ? import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from design import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 2"))
  
  
#from dialog import Ui_Dialog        
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(Dialog)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 256, 192))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "1")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        
        
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.btnA = False                                             # +++
        self.btnB = False                                             # +++
        
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.add_A_B)                 # +++
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)                  # +++
  
    def a_load(self):
        self.treeWidget.clear()
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, "A")
#        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.addA)
#        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        self.btnA = True                                             # +++
        self.btnB = False                                            # +++
 
    def add_A_B(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Добавить', 'Введите название')
        
        if text and self.btnA:                                       # +++
            self.parent.pushButton.setText(text)                     # +++
        elif text and self.btnB:                                     # +++
            self.parent.pushButton_2.setText(text)                   # +++           
            
#        return text
#        self.close()
    
    def b_load(self):
        self.treeWidget.clear()
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, "B")
#        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.addA)
#        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        self.btnB = True                                             # +++
        self.btnA = False                                            # +++
 
#    def addB(self):
#        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Добавить', 'Введите название')
#        return text
#        self.close()
 
 
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.add_functions()
        self.dialog = Dialog(self)
 
    def add_functions(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.A)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.B)
 
    def A(self):
        self.dialog.a_load()
        self.dialog.exec()
 
    def B(self):
        self.dialog.b_load()
        self.dialog.exec()
 
 
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: получилось спасибо

Comment: @Достон пожалуйста.

Comment: А как сделать проверку чтобы при нажатии ОК проверялось условие и если это условие правильное то закрывать диалог если не правильно то вернуться в диалог например в данном случае если не ввел текст то не закрывать диалог?

Comment: @Достон если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.